# Pygame Help Trying to add apples in Snakegame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('slither')

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (252,25,25)
blue = (20,20,250)
purple = (90,33,146)



movement_size = 10
block_size = 20

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
def message_to_screen(msg,colour):
screen_text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])

def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

lead_x = display_width/2.0
lead_y = display_height/2.0

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

randAppleX = random.randrange(0, display_width-block_size)
randAppleY = random.randrange(display_height-block_size, 0)

while not gameExit:

    while gameOver == True:
        gameDisplay.fill(purple)
        message_to_screen("Game Over, Press 'C' to play again or 'Q' to Quit", red)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameLoop()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change -= movement_size
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change += movement_size
                lead_y_change= 0

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change -= movement_size
                lead_x_change= 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change += movement_size
                lead_x_change= 0

            if lead_x >= 782 or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= 582 or lead_y < 0:
                gameOver = True

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX, randAppleY, block_size, block_size])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x, lead_y, block_size, block_size])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(11)


pygame.quit()
quit()


gameLoop()
```

I was trying to add 'apples' in my snake game. However I was troubled in doing so. Any help debugging code would be very much appreciated! I'm getting some error on lines; 94,42 and 218 something has gone horribly wrong with the randrange stuff.

http://i63.tinypic.com/1h4ggj.png <----- To See

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error happens in

```
randAppleY = random.randrange(display_height-block_size, 0)
```

As the error stack trace indicates that `randrange` function got parameters start=580, stop=0. From inspecting the source file for this function shows that the default value for step is 1.
This is causing the problem as 0 is less than 580 and connot be reached by adding 1 (step parameter) any number of times.

What you can do to fix this is either pass step parameter as -1

```
randAppleY = random.randrange(display_height-block_size, 0, -1)
```

Or pass the smaller value as start and larger value as stop parameter

```
randAppleY = random.randrange(0, display_height-block_size)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you're help I used the second method you inputted and it worked. However, was I wrong in assuming that the first parameter in the randrange bracket was the x-axis and the second the y? Also i'm not sure what you mean by 'step'

Comment: Consider randrange(start=1,stop=6) will give possible values of 1,2,3,4,5,. randrange(start=1,stop=5, setp=2) will give possible values of 1,3,5.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('slither')

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (252,25,25)
blue = (20,20,250)
purple = (90,33,146)



movement_size = 10
block_size = 20

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameExit = gameOver = False

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
def message_to_screen(msg,colour):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])

def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

lead_x = display_width/2.0
lead_y = display_height/2.0

lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

randAppleX = random.randint(0, display_width-block_size)
randAppleY = random.randint(0,display_height-block_size)

while not gameExit:

    while gameOver:
        gameDisplay.fill(purple)
        message_to_screen("Game Over, Press 'C' to play again or 'Q' to Quit", red)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    gameLoop()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change -= movement_size
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change += movement_size
                lead_y_change= 0

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change -= movement_size
                lead_x_change= 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change += movement_size
                lead_x_change= 0

            if lead_x >= 782 or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= 582 or lead_y < 0:
                gameOver = True

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX, randAppleY, block_size, block_size])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x, lead_y, block_size, block_size])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(11)


pygame.quit()
quit()


gameLoop()
```

Comment: That should fix your problem, however I believe there is still some work to be done... :P

Comment: I prefer to use randint instead of randrange, fyi

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. What does the first value then in the randint(first,second) represent? the 0...

Comment: My pleasure, the syntax for the randint() function are randint(minimum,maximum) so if you were to enter randint(0,50) it would return a random value between 0 and 50.

Comment: So in this case, the x location of your apple will be a random location between 0 and the width of the screen minus the with of the apple. (clever forethought might i say)

Comment: Haha thank you, although I am just following a tutorial :P I can't take any credit yet.. Is there any way to PM you? I keep running into bugs here and there lol

Comment: You can contact me @ 3ndermon@gmail.com, however I'm no expert... Either way I'd be happy to try!